# How would I attach feet to my product?

Tags: joinery, wood, plywood

For my GCSE Design and Technology coursework, I am making an MP3 docking station: basically a speaker. My design features a plywood box that sits on a base, which is the same shape as the box but larger than the box. This base is very thin, 3 mm thick, and I am making metal feet on a lathe to attach to the base. My question is: How do I attach feet to this thin base, or would I attach them to the base underneath the ply box?

Comment: Further to @LeeG's Answer, if you want to glue the feet on permanently, I'd use use epoxy. Contact cements can make quite a good long-term bond, but epoxy is a surer bet. If you choose epoxy 3 additional points that you might need, 1) you must texture the mating surface of the metal for the epoxy to grip to it (coarse sanding scratches are sufficient, <60 grit ideally) 2) lightly sand the ply just before you glue 3) DO NOT clamp hard. Epoxy doesn't need clamp pressure to bond and if you squeeze too hard you risk squeezing out too much of the glue, resulting in what's called a starved joint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how much work you want to go to.  The easiest would be some sort of adhesive.  Depending on the material the base is made from, you could use an epoxy, contact cement, or silicon caulk.  Even the spray adhesives would likely work.

You could also add a threaded hole on the top of your legs and attach the legs to the base with a machine screw.  The top of the screw could be made decorative to make it part of the design.

How you make it will largely depend on the goal of the design - production prototype vs one-off item.